# how to display accounts created by a specific user?

Tags: user-accounts

Is there a chance to display accounts created by user "usertest"?
Was trying to find something on google but unsuccessfully,

thanks in advance,

Comment: Unless usertest has root privileges, there's no way for that account to create accounts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a tag with some kind of context to this question. The answer is assuming user accounts in some kind of POSIX environment, but for all we know you could be talking about database users, LDAP users, or users under any number of almost infinite other contexts.

Comment: Sorry, it appears as though @Jens edited out the reference to `bash`, leaving the question without context. A tag of some kind would still be appropriate, or moving the question to [unix.se], since there appears to be no programming involved here, might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, users are not bash/shell specific. Also 'Created by' data for user doesn't exist. You can only guess by using history and auth/secure log files.